# Subset matrix based on cell values and drop rows/columns which don't satisfy a criterion

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a 60*60 matrix which is a bit hard to navigate, and I want to concentrate only on certain values in the matrix. So my idea would be to drop all the cells if their value is below/above a certain threshold, and if all the values in a certain row/column are below the threshold, they would be dropped as well.

Let's say I want to drop everything where the value is below 0.5

Example input:

```
              abcd       abcde          ab
abcd   0.000000000  0.44757748  0.61945319  
abcde  0.447577477  0.00000000  0.33773497  
ab     0.619453192  0.33773497  0.00000000
```

Example output:

```
          abcd          ab     
abcd                0.61945319 
ab     0.619453192
```

So in this case, the abcde column had no values above 0.5 and is dropped completely (since it's symmetrical, also the row is dropped). Also, all the other values which once held numbers are now empty. I've simplified the matrix and can see the cells which I want easily. Now, this is a 3*3 matrix so it's not that useful, but it might be useful for a matrix with lots of values.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: You can use `rowSums` or `colSums` on the condition as [illustrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37281038/2204410) to achieve that. E.g: `mat[rowSums(mat > 0.5) >= 1, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  add_rownames() %>%
  gather(key, value, -rowname) %>%
  filter(value > 0.5) %>%
  spread(key, value, fill = "")
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#
#  rowname         ab        abcd
#    (chr)      (chr)       (chr)
#1      ab            0.619453192
#2    abcd 0.61945319
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(abcd = c(0, 0.447577477, 0.619453192), abcde = c(0.44757748, 
0, 0.33773497), ab = c(0.61945319, 0.33773497, 0)), .Names = c("abcd", 
"abcde", "ab"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("abcd", "abcde", "ab"))
```

Comment: It is better to use `fill = NA` imo, as that doesn't change the class of the values.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I agree. This is actually pretty inefficient and result in a poor data structure for further analysis. I just mimicked OP desired output.

Answer (score 2):

In order to drop the rows and columns that have no value above `0.5`, you can use:

```
mat[rowSums(mat > 0.5) >= 1, colSums(mat > 0.5) >= 1]
```

which gives:

```
          abcd        ab
abcd 0.0000000 0.6194532
ab   0.6194532 0.0000000
```

For replacing individual values, see @Oliver's answer. Replacing with `NA`'s is better than replacing with an empty character value as the latter will change the class of the values of the entire matrix.

---

Used data:

```
mat <- structure(c(0, 0.447577477, 0.619453192, 0.44757748, 0, 0.33773497, 0.61945319, 0.33773497, 0), 
                 .Dim = c(3L, 3L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(c("abcd", "abcde", "ab"), c("abcd", "abcde", "ab")))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
myMatrix[myMatrix < 0.5] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. Just a simple followup: how would I define a new matrix with these new NA values, so I don't lose the original one? (because it's already assigned via <-)

Comment: @praznin just make a copy first with `mymat2 <- mymat` and then replace with `NA`'s.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks :)